# What's the most efficient way to move to the end of a paragraph/sentence in Vim?

Tags: vim, vi

I write prose in Vim in markdown, and many times I want to jump to the end of text-objects to edit them. Some text objects are easy to navigate: words and WORDS are easy (using `e` and `E`), but sentences and paragraphs are a little less efficient. I use `}gE` and `)gE` to jump to the ends of paragraphs and sentences (respectively).

Before I bind `)gE` and `}gE` to a single key, is there another (more efficient) way to get to the end of a sentence or paragraph in Vim?

Comment: I think you can define a command to do this using [this plugin](https://github.com/kana/vim-textobj-user). I haven't checked it though, just skimmed through the docs.

Comment: It's more keystrokes (and a bit frustrating to have to change modes twice) but you might like using visual mode with `visv`

Answer (score 1):

I can't say for the end of paragraph, but you can use `$` to go to the end of line. And while we're on the topic, here are two more commands for navigating sentences:

`0` to go to the start of the line

`^` to go to the first non-white character in the line

```py
def sample():
&   print('sample string')
```

To properly explain the difference between the two, let's say you're in an indented code block, and you want to go to the very first position in the line (marked as `&` in the sample code), but if you wanted to go to the *first non-white character*, in this case, `p`, then you would use `^`

Answer (score -1):

There was a similar discussion [here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2238/how-do-i-move-to-the-last-character-in-a-sentence.).

So I'm guessing your approach is probably the most efficient one.